# Firefox doesn't respect cookie policy for google

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

Trying to tune my privacy on Firefox. I want to be able to read my gmail, cookies should be accepted in general but only Gmail related cookies should be kept.

From the settings below you can clearly see that behavior set. After restarting Firefox I can see that there are still cookies from `google.com`.
Isn't what the option **Keep until I close Firefox** should do?

Clean profile, no addons. These are my settings:

[image]

And the Exceptions:

[image]

And in `about:config`

[image]

This is it, clean install, no addons.

Remarks:

- I don't want to dissalow cookies from google.com as this breaks gmail. But I want all `google.com` cookies that aren't in the `accounts` and `mail` subdomains to be deleted when I close firefox.
- I am aware of `CookieSafe` and other plugins, but since firefox implies that does what I want there is no reason to bloat my profile. If its a bug it should be reported.
- Other browsers, addons, hosts file, proxies and extraterrestrial technology aren't an option.

Comment: May be url with placeholder work e.g. `https://*.google.com`

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does 2 tricky things with the exception list.

1. Any domain you add will have the `http://` protocol appended if you do not
   specify one. In turn, Firefox will only respect the exception if the protocols
   match, so you might need to change it to `https://`
2. Firefox also adds a wildcard to any domain added, so you end up with this:

   - google.com: also matches www.google.com and mail.google.com
   - www.google.com: also matches zzz.www.google.com (if that existed)
   - stackexchange.com: also matches meta.stackexchange.com
   - meta.stackexchange.com: also matches unix.meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that all you need to do to complete your exceptions list,
is to add to the list
`https://www.google.com` with the permission of `Allow for Session`.